# Copying range to active cell range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that inserts 12 lines above the user's active cell. I am trying to get the code to copy a specific range from another sheet and paste it into the newly created rows. I keep getting a runtime error of 424. How can I solve this?

Code below

```
With ActiveSheet

    For i = 1 To 12
        ActiveCell.Rows.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next i

    Sheets("The Hidden Works").Range("A2:U13").Copy.Range.ActiveCell
End With
```

Comment: Changing `.Copy.Range.ActiveCell` to `.Copy  ActiveCell` will fix the problem

Comment: And, based on your comment to an answer, use `.Copy  ActiveCell.EntireRow.Range("A1")`

Answer (score 1):

I would set your range that you are wanting to copy to a variable first, then perform the procedure with your selection. This can possibly assist you with debugging down the road (and ensure that you are working with the correct objects).

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim rngToCopy As Range
    Set rngToCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("The Hidden Works").Range("A2:U13")

    rngToCopy.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Does almost exactly what I need to do. The issue is that I need the paste to align to Column A, no matter where the active cell is on the row. Suggestions?

Comment: To paste starting in column A, a simple change would be to change `Selection` to `Selection.EntireRow.Range("A1")` (or you could use `Cells(Selection.Row, "A")` if you like)

Comment: Solved it with YowE3K and K.Davis